# setting variables

Tags: bash, unix

hello I am trying to set two files to variables, does anyone know how I would do this? This code finds duplicate file names and then prints them if they are the same. But I need to be able to delete them and get the pathname.
Thanks

```
find -type f -exec md5sum '{}' ';' | sort | uniq --all-repeated=separate -w 33 | cut -c 35-
```

So basically I have this md5sum | filename in a file. I am reading and finding the duplicates based on the md5sum. However I may also want to delete the duplicate and print the filepath. Any suggstions?

Answer (score 1):

Just assign to a variable, nothing special needed:

```
$ X="myFile.py"
$ echo $X
myFile.py
```

Comment: I dont understand what that just did

Comment: Sorry, the question is a bit confusing.  Can you expand a little more on what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: see addition in my first message

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear, but I think you want to use a read loop:

```
ComplexFindCommand | while read PATHNAME ; do
    echo "This pathname is $PATHNAME"
done
```